# code wont upload to arduino starter kit

Tags: arduino-uno, uploading, mac-os

My operating system : OS X EL CAPITAN

Please help I was trying to do project 05 Mood cue of the arduino starter kit. I completed setting up my board and writing the code and when I tried to upload I got this error message:

```
Arduino: 1.7.10 (Mac OS X), Board: "Arduino Uno"

Sketch uses 1,030 bytes (3%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32,256 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2,039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/tty.usbmodem1411": Device not         configured
ioctl("TIOCMGET"): Inappropriate ioctl for device
Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.

  This report would have more information with
  "Show verbose output during compilation"
  enabled in File > Preferences.
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Try to use the official and original Arduino software from arduino.cc [current version](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software)

Comment: @Personagem i tried to download it and it still would not work this is the error it gave me now :

Sketch uses 444 bytes (1%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32,256 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2,039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/tty.usbmodem1411": Device not configured
Problem uploading to board.  

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.

Comment: It sounds like there is an issue with your USB serial connection.

Comment: @harry_p_6 thanks for the response harry. What do i do now? is there a away to fix it? im very new to all this

Comment: @harry_p_6 Thank you Harry i managed to fix it by downloading CH341SER_MAC.zip just in case someone has the same problem http://www.wch.cn/downfile/178

Comment: your arduino kid may not be connected properly else configure the board

Comment: @PendukeniPandeni Glad you managed to find the solution. Add your comment as an answer and mark it as accepted solution.

Comment: You're welcome. As @Personagem said, please answer your own question and accept the answer so that it does not count as an unanswered question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you Harry i managed to fix it by downloading CH341SER_MAC.zip just in case someone has the same problem wch.cn/downfile/178